# Am I being thick? MySQL: "Not unique table/alias" on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the following SQL statement which returns "*Not unique table/alias*". I'm fairly sure I'm just missing something obvious here, possibly not being specific enough when referring to `StockID` as it's a common field name to `Stock` and `SuppliersStock`. Primary Key in `Stock`, Foreign Key in `SuppliersStock`

```
SELECT Stock.BuyingPrice, SuppliersStock.StockID, SuppliersStock.Quantity
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN Stock on Stock.StockID = SuppliersStock.StockID 
WHERE Stock.StockID = <some-integer />
```

The `Stock` table has specific information about stock, `Suppliers` has info on suppliers and `SuppliersStock` has information orders for new stock with foreign key references to `Stock` and `Suppliers`.

What I want to do is return the `BuyingPrice` (from `Stock`), `StockID`, `Quantity` (from `SuppliersStock`) fields so I can produce a list of costs for ordering in new stock.

*Disclaimer: I know, another question on SQL joins. Don't hurt me! I've Googled, I've searched but I'm a bit befuddled and I've honestly tried to look for a similar question to learn more about what I can do to solve this myself but come up trumps. Please help?*

Comment: Well, you are using the table `Stock` twice without giving them an alias, of course its gonna throw that error to you. Besides, you are using `SuppliersStock.StockID` on your join condition, but you aren't using that table

Comment: Funny how the answer to the question in the title is "Yes, you are being thick" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are skipping the alias to `SuppliersStock`, or it is a different table:

```
/* If SuppliersStock is a different table */
SELECT Stock.BuyingPrice, SuppliersStock.StockID, SuppliersStock.Quantity
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN SuppliersStock on Stock.StockID = SuppliersStock.StockID 
WHERE Stock.StockID = <some-integer />

/* If SuppliersStock is the same table, needing an alias */
SELECT Stock.BuyingPrice, SuppliersStock.StockID, SuppliersStock.Quantity
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN Stock AS SuppliersStock on Stock.StockID = SuppliersStock.StockID 
WHERE Stock.StockID = <some-integer />
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, and yes SuppliersStock is a different table. Guess I was being thick after all! :)

Answer (score 10):

Your 'from' and 'left join' both refer to the the same table 'Stock'. Change one of them to refer to 'SupplierStock'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're joining `Stock` with `Stock` instead of `SuppliersStock`, so when you say `Stock.StockID` MySQL doesn't know which of the two are you referring to.

I'm guessing you wanted to do this:

```
SELECT Stock.BuyingPrice, SuppliersStock.StockID, SuppliersStock.Quantity
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN SuppliersStock on Stock.StockID = SuppliersStock.StockID 
WHERE Stock.StockID = <some-integer />
```

Answer (score 1):

you are joining Stock on itself, which means the query doesn't know which Stock you are referencing.
If this is what you want, make an alias for the joined table: `JOIN Stock AS SuppliersStock`